# Apache ignite QueryEntity Based Configuration

Tags: caching, h2, ignite

My  model (i.e. valueType) is wrapped Map -

```
class Model { 
  Map<String,Object> data; 
  Object  get(String key){} 
}
```

How to get all "Models" ordered by data's some keys.

I want to execute this query on Models cache "select * from Model ORDER BY name* " where the "name" is some key of the "data". 
How can I do that  my "indexes" to be my "data" 's some keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't index collection elements. Instead, you should have `name` as a separate field and configure it to be indexed in corresponding `QueryEntity`.